# shell script to find and replace using sed command

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting and have a request to modify multiple files. I have
the input as below

```
#this is line1 for file1@abc.com     
test line 2  
test line 3  
this is line4 for file1@ABC.com  
test line 5  
this is line6 for file1@Abc.COM
```

and need output like

```
#this is line1 for file1@abc.com   
test line 2  
test line 3   
##this is line4 for file1@ABC.com  
this is line4 for file1@XYZ.com  
test line 5   
##this is line6 for file1@Abc.COM  
this is line6 for file1@Xyz.COM
```

I tried the below command to do this changes and it changes only abc to xyz and other are not getting changed

```
sed '/^[^#].*@abc.com/ {h; s/^/##/; p; g; s/abc.com/xyz.com/;}'
```

Please help me to modify the script case-insentitive

Comment: Glenn... Please help

Comment: what do the bold lines mean?

Comment: So replacement is not static `xyz.com` and it has to match case also like `Abc.COM => Xyz.COM`?

Comment: Not necessarily. Abc.com can become xyz.com, and ABC.com can become xyz.com. The only concern is that the read from the source should be case insensitive. But it would be better if the source and target matches if there is an option

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to do case insensitive matching and replacement.

There's no good and portable way of doing this with `sed`. You can instead use e.g. `[Aa]` to match either `A` or `a`:

```
sed '/^[^#].*@[Aa][Bb][Cc]\.[Cc][Oo][Mm]/ {
        h; s/^/##/; p; g; s/[Aa][Bb][Cc]\.[Cc][Oo][Mm]/xyz.com/;
     }'
```

You can rewrite this to a single substitution to save some bytes:

```
sed 's/^\([^#].*\)[Aa][Bb][Cc]\.[Cc][Oo][Mm]\(.*\)/##&\
\1xyz.com\2/'
```

However, if you're using GNU sed (and not e.g. OSX sed), then you can use the `I` flag to `s`:

```
sed 's/^\([^#].*\)abc\.com\(.*\)/##&\n\1xyz.com\2/I'  # GNU only
```

Comment: I am using Hp-ux and I flag is not working, may be i have try the first option